# Why am i getting the error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"?

Tags: java, swing, exception, zero, divide

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>         at factoroperations.compute(factoroperations.java:21)
>         at factorframe$buttonhandler.actionPerformed(factorframe.java:71)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
> 18)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
> a:2341)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
> .java:402)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259
> )
>         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
> istener.java:252)
>         at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
>         at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>         at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
>         at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832
> )
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>         at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
>
>
> main.java:76)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
> main.java:87)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
> main.java:76)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
> ad.java:211)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
> java:128)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
> ad.java:117)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> ```

```java
//Project: A program that factors numbers

//This defines the properties of the user interface

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class factorframe extends JFrame
{//declare all the variables
    private JLabel integerlabel;
    private JTextField integerfield;
    private JLabel factorslabel;
    private JTextField factorsfield;
    private JLabel namelabel;
    private JButton computebutton;
    private JButton clearbutton;
    private JButton exitbutton;
    private String integerstring;
    private long integer;
    private String factorsstring;
    private int factors;
    private factoroperations factormachine;

 public factorframe() //This is the constructor
 {  //add all buttons and fields
    super("Factor Frame");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    namelabel = new JLabel("Integer Factorization  By Michael Daigh");
    add(namelabel);
    integerlabel = new JLabel("Enter an integer:");
    add(integerlabel);
    integerfield = new JTextField(20);
    add(integerfield);
    factorslabel = new JLabel("The factors are:");
    add(factorslabel);
    factorsfield = new JTextField(20);
    add(factorsfield);
    computebutton = new JButton("Compute Factors");
    add(computebutton);
    clearbutton = new JButton("Clear");
    add(clearbutton);
    exitbutton = new JButton("Exit");
    add(exitbutton);
    buttonhandler myhandler = new buttonhandler();
    computebutton.addActionListener(myhandler);
    clearbutton.addActionListener(myhandler);
    exitbutton.addActionListener(myhandler);
    factormachine = new factoroperations();
 }//End of constructor method
 private class buttonhandler implements ActionListener
   {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == computebutton)//if user clicks compute factors
            {//computes the factors of the number
                integerstring = integerfield.getText();//get the number
                integer = Long.parseLong(integerstring);
                factorsstring = factoroperations.compute(integer);
                factorsfield.setText(factorsstring);//display the factors
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == clearbutton)//if user clicks clear
            {//clears all data in integer field and factor field
                integer=0;
                integerfield.setText("");
                factors=0;
                factorsfield.setText("");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == exitbutton)//if user clicks exit
            {//exits the program
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Unknown error");
        }//End of actionPerformed
    }//End of buttonhandler class
}//End of factorframe class


//Project: A program that factors numbers

//This contains the algorithm used by this project.

public class factoroperations
{
 public static String compute(long integer)
 {
    String factor="";//initialize the factor string
    int check = 1;//initialize the prime check
    for(int i=2; i<=integer/2; i++)
    {
        if(integer%i==0)//i is a factor of the number
        {
            for(int k=2; k<i; k++)//check if it is prime
            {
                if(i%k ==0)
                {
                    check = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    check = 0;
            }
            if(check == 0 || i == 2)//display the prime factors only
            {
                factor = factor + " " + i + "P";
            }
            else if(check == 1)//display all other factors
                factor = factor + " " + i;
        }
    }
    if(factor == "")//if number does not factor, it is already prime
    {
        factor = "No factors. It is a prime number";
    }
    return factor;
 }
}//End factoroperations class


//Project: A program that factors numbers

//This activates the user interface.
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class testfactor
{public static void main(String[] args)
    {factorframe myframe = new factorframe();
     myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     myframe.setSize(325,225);
     myframe.setVisible(true);
    }//End of main
}//End of class testfactor
```

Comment: Which line of cause throws this exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: he's saying your code doesn't have line numbers, so the stack trace isn't very helpful since we can't tell which line is raising the exception (unless we count them manually).

Comment: The exception gives you line numbers in your code to tell you where the exception is occurring. You need to look at that line of code to see what could be not working correctly.  you'll also want to tell us which line it is.

Comment: line 21 in factoroperations.java is the "if(integer%i==0)"              it is in the factoroperations class.

Comment: it never divides by 0 is why i dont understand what is going on. the 'i' starts at 2 how can it go to zero?

Comment: I too don't see how this code is producing that error. Are you sure that this is the code that you are running?

Comment: yes. im pretty sure. the error only occurs tho if i use a number greater than 4,294,967,295.

Comment: Perhaps this is something we should have been aware of in your original question?!?

Comment: yea didn't think about that until now. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting int overflow and are dividing by 0. While the `integer` parameter is a long, your i is an int and it will overflow if it tries to increment to match the size of the large long parameter, and when it overflows, its value can be 0, negative, or lord knows what.

One possible solution: your for loop indices should both be longs, not ints.

Also, for what it's worth, it's quite confusing giving a *long* parameter or variable the name `integer`!

Comment: That did it. Thank you. That makes a lot of sense now. Haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You never divide by 0, so it shouldn't produce this error, something is messed up here. However, I'd like to point out a few things to fix:

- Don't call your `long` integer; this is just plain stupid. Give it a more meaningful name, such as `numberToFactor` or just `number`.
- "`if(factor == "")`":  Use `if(factor.equals(""))` instead, you must use `.equals` on strings rather than `==`
- Read up on `StringBuilder`; you can use this to make your code more efficient with all that string concatenation in your for loops.

EDIT: With this new info from your comment, Hovercraft is right. Change your loop counters to be of the type `long` just like your number to factor. If they are int's, when they hit 2^31-1 (maximum int value), they will cause errors. Using a long however give's more memory to the number, allowing it to be larger.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just started Java in school and this is my first program. Teacher doesn't really teach so I haven't looked into all the things I can do. I will try and look at StringBuilder. Thanks again.

Comment: @GolfinGamer Yup, also please mark hovercraft's as the correct answer, and to show your thanks +1 both of our answers :) Thanks